# Only letters function

Tags: python

I want to write a function where it filters out all characters that are not letters. 
For example,

> allLetters("Hell4208o@World.com") --> “HelloWorldcom”

I know how to do this using built in functions like, `isalpha`, `.join`, `.append`.

```
def allLetters2(phrase):
   l = []
   for characters in phrase:
      if characters.isalpha():
         l.append(characters)
   return ''.join(l)
```

But I am looking for a way where I don't use those functions and use only a `for` loop and `string.ascii_letters`. Similar to this structure:

```
def allLetters2(phrase):    
   for characters in phrase:
      if characters == string.ascii_letters:            
         return characters
```

Comment: Why the bizarre requirement not to use `isalpha`?  `''.join(c for c in s if c.isalpha())` is straightforward enough.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I am a newb in to coding and want to learn the very basics first.

Comment: `if c.isalpha()` is no less basic than `if c in string.ascii_letters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use join just concatenate:

```
import string
def all_letters(s):
    final = ""
    for char in s:
        if char in string.ascii_letters:
            final += char
    return final
In [78]: all_letters("Hell4208o@World.com")
Out[78]: 'HelloWorldcom'
```

Some timings for the different approaches:

```
In [90]: %%timeit                                                            
    final = ""
    for char in s:
        if char in string.ascii_letters:
            final += char
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.97 µs per loop

In [91]: timeit ''.join(char for char in s if char in string.ascii_letters)

100000 loops, best of 3: 4.62 µs per loop

In [92]: timeit ''.join([char for char in s if char in string.ascii_letters])

100000 loops, best of 3: 3.8 µs per loop

In [98]: timeit "".join([x for x in s if x.isalpha()])
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.01 µs per loop

In [102]: timeit s.translate(None, ''.join(set(s)-set(ascii_letters)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.13 µs per loop
```

Comment: For small strings, the join(list-comp) technique `"".join([x for x in s if x.isalpha()])` is best, but for longer strings `re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z]', '', s)` can be significantly faster. On my old machine (using a randomly generated string), the crossover point is around len(s)==50. For len(s)==1000, the regex timing is around 60% of the timing of the join(list-comp) technique.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
''.join(char for char in pharse if char in string.ascii_letters)
```

When you do `for characters in phrase` characters is actually a single char from the phrase. The loops goes over them one by one. `string.ascii_letters` is a string containing all letters - a single char from phrase would never equal that. This makes your check - `characters == string.ascii_letters` illogical.

You should, instead, check if the character is `in` string.ascii_letters. This tells us if it's an ascii letter.

```
In [51]: 'a' in 'abcd'
Out[51]: True
```

Your code also has a misplaced return statement. Even if the condition was true, it would return only a single character. Your code could be rebuilt as:

```
def allLetters2(phrase):   
   okchars = [] 
   for character in phrase:
      if character in string.ascii_letters:            
         okchars.append(character)
   return ''.join(okchars)
```

Which is exactly what my code above does - only it uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to make it shorter and more readable.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating! How will I code it without using `.append` and `.join`?

Comment: @Robben the way to write this without using `append` and `join`, is to store the characters in a string as you go. However this is way less efficient and elegant, so I suggest not doing that. This goes from 'basic' to 'wrong'

Comment: Okay then, I will take your word. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, questions like filteing/deleting or selecting a subset of character sets are best handled by [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), if used in proper sense

**code**

```
def allLetters(st):
    from string import ascii_letters
    return st.translate(None, ''.join(set(st)-set(ascii_letters)))
```

**usage**

```
>>> allLetters("Hell4208o@World.com")
'HelloWorldcom'
```